# Некоректно выводится плагин tablepress

Tags: wordpress

Я создал свою тему на wordpress и подключил плагин tablepress. Но на странице выводится только шорткод плагина, а таблицы нет. Что мне нужно сделать чтобы все исправить?
[image: нерабочая тема]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо выводить контент либо через стандартную функцию `the_content()`, которая применяет шорткоды к контенту, либо через `do_shortcode( $content )`, где `$content` - содержимое страницы, которое вы достаёте из базы.